# A complex limit to know if it exists or not for each complex

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital

I would love some advice on how to approach the following limit:
For each complex number z, determine:
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{1+n^{2}z} $$
What i tried is the following: 
Let's note the following
$$\left| \frac{1}{1+n^{2}z} \right| = \frac{1}{\left| 1 + n^{2}z\right|} = \frac{1}{\left| 1 + n^{2}(r(cos(\theta)+i(sen(\theta)))\right|} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1+n^{2})r^{2}cos(\theta)^{2} +r^{2}sen(\theta)^{2}}} \lt 1$$
$$\left| z_n \right|\to 0$$
therefore $$ z_n \to 0$$

then the limit is equal to 0, is my idea correct?

Comment: Don't forget to handle the special case where $z=0$.

Comment: It is not true that $|z_n| \lt 1$, try for example $z=-\frac{1}{2}, \;n=1$. It is also not true that $|z_n| \lt 1$ $\implies |z_n| \to 0$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan You are right, in this case there is no limit, right?

Comment: @IrukaC.M. As [Ryszard Szwarc's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4681292/a-complex-limit-to-know-if-it-exists-or-not-for-each-complex?noredirect=1#comment9899541_4681309) states, with $z = 0$, the value of $\frac{1}{1+n^{2}z}$ is $0$ for *all* $n$, so the limit exists and is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid applying the polar coordinates. If $z\neq 0$ by the triangle inequality we have $$|1+n^2z|\ge n^2|z|-1>0,\  {\rm for}\ n>|z|^{-1/2}$$ Hence $$|x_n|\le {1\over n^2|z|-1}\to 0$$

Comment: It's true, thank you very much for the help :3 and last question in the case |z| = 0 the limit does not exist right?

Comment: For $z=0$ we have $(1+n^2z)^{-1}=1,$ so the limit exists and is equal $1.$